# Navigating between different stackscreen in react-navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
)
```

How can I navigate from signInScreen to HomeScreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a context to handle the authentification flow and on your app launch check if a token or anything is already set.

```
const Index = () => {
  const [authState, dispatch] = useAuthContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    const boostrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken = null;
      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Restoring token failed');
      }
      restoreToken({ token: userToken }, dispatch);
    };
    boostrapAsync();
  }, []);

  if (authState.isLoading) {
    return (
      <SplashScreen />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Root>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <UIProvider reducer={UIReducer} initialState={initialStateUIReducer}>
          {authState.userToken ? (
            <UserProvider reducer={UserReducer} initialState={initialStateUserReducer}>
              <AppNavigation />
            </UserProvider>
          ) : <AuthNavigation />}
        </UIProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Root>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

These problems can be solved with a splash screen. I think you should collect all screens under one tag. Then, make a splash screen. After that, you can control the parameter is called isSignedIn in the SplashScreen. Then you navigate the screen which you want.